# ng-repeat over JSON array inside Array after select

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a project where i have a JSON object containing 'Standarder' each of these 'Standarder' has a number of 'indikatorer' ( 1-10). I can now iterate over them all and sort them so they apear in the right order.

I can also put them in a  and  . but I would want to make a ng-repeat that iterates over the specific Standard i choose from the list and show the indikatores for that specific Standard.

I have this code running now  :

Pluncker is here :  http://plnkr.co/edit/EM4OuXVbpi5HSVzr8PAq?p=preview

```js
{
    "Standarder": [
        {
            "SektorID": 2,
            "SektorNavn": "Apotek",
            "StandardVersionID": 6,
            "Version": 2,
            "Udgave": 1,
            "IKAS_standard": [
                {
                    "StandardID": 170,
                    "Kode": "1.1.1",
                    "Kategori": "Organisatoriske standarder",
                    "Tema": "Ledelse",
                    "Titel": "Virksomhedsgrundlag (1/5)",
                    "Formaal": "At apoteket beskriver mission, vision og værdier for apoteket, og at sikre, at disse afspejles i apotekets samlede opgavevaretagelse.",
                    "Indhold": "Standarden er en rammestandard og sætter rammen for øvrige akkrediteringsstandarder.   Standarden er grundlæggende for apotekets virksomhed og afspejles i apotekets øvrige retningsgivende dokumenter.   Virksomhedsgrundlaget tager udgangspunkt i apotekets lovgivningsmæssige bemyndigelse og strategien for apotekerne i Danmark. Virksomhedsgrundlaget afspejler den forpligtelse og de rettigheder, som det indebærer at have en apotekerbevilling.   Virksomhedsgrundlaget består af mission, vision og værdier for de opgaver, apoteket varetager. Desuden vil et virksomhedsgrundlag ofte indeholde fokusområder/målsætninger, som apoteket skal arbejde med for at missionen og visionen kan opfyldes. Virksomhedsgrundlaget er integreret i den daglige ledelse og afspejles i apotekets ledelsesstruktur og personalepolitik.    Virksomhedsgrundlaget er grundlæggende for apotekets professionelle og etiske rolle over for kunder, samarbejdspartnere og personale. Der er således en klar sammenhæng mellem virksomhedsgrundlaget og de signaler, apoteket sender, eksempelvis via vindues- og apoteksudsmykning, varesortiment, pressekontakt, kundekontakt og kundedialog.    En del af denne standard omhandler implementering af virksomheds-grundlaget. Arbejdet med virksomhedsgrundlaget sker i dialog mellem ledelsen, kvalitetsgruppen og personalet.   Virksomhedsgrundlaget bliver herved en fælles platform for styring, drift og udvikling for alle ansatte på apoteket.   Apotekets evaluering af, hvorvidt der er sammenhæng mellem virksomhedsgrundlaget, apotekets praksis og de fastsatte kvalitetsmål, herunder personalets oplevelse af sammenhængen, kan eksempelvis afdækkes som en del af en større medarbejdertilfredshedsundersøgelse, kundetilfredshedsundersøgelse og i forhold til opfyldelse af servicemål.   Standarden har sammenhæng med:   Trin 1 og 4 i alle akkrediteringsstandarder, da virksomhedsgrundlaget danner grundlag for apotekets arbejde.   1.1.3 Planlægning og drift. Virksomhedsgrundlaget bruges som udgangspunkt for apotekets planlægning og drift.",
                    "Krydsreferencer": "",
                    "Anvendelsesomraade": "",
                    "IKAS_indikator": [
                        {
                            "IndikatorID": 1157,
                            "IndikatorNummer": 1,
                            "TrinNummer": 1,
                            "IndikatorTekst": "Der foreligger et virksomhedsgrundlag, der afspejler apotekets ønskede rolle i lokalsamfundet og sundhedssektoren og som beskriver apotekets:    mission vision værdier",
                            "IndikatorGruppeID": -1,
                            "IndikatorFundKategorier": [
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 1,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "OK"
                                },
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 2,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Problem"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "IndikatorID": 1158,
                            "IndikatorNummer": 2,
                            "TrinNummer": 1,
                            "IndikatorTekst": "Der foreligger retningslinjer, der beskriver, hvordan ledelsen vil sikre, at virksomhedsgrundlaget danner grundlag for det daglige arbejde.",
                            "IndikatorGruppeID": -1,
                            "IndikatorFundKategorier": [
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 1,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "OK"
                                },
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 2,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Problem"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "IndikatorID": 1159,
                            "IndikatorNummer": 3,
                            "TrinNummer": 2,
                            "IndikatorTekst": "Apotekeren og personalet kender virksomhedsgrundlaget, som danner grundlag for det daglige arbejde.",
                            "IndikatorGruppeID": -1,
                            "IndikatorFundKategorier": [
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 3,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Konsistent impl."
                                },
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 4,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Enkelte afv."
                                },
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 5,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Svag impl."
                                },
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 6,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Mangl. Impl."
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "IndikatorID": 1160,
                            "IndikatorNummer": 4,
                            "TrinNummer": 3,
                            "IndikatorTekst": "En gang årligt evaluerer ledelsen virksomhedsgrundlaget.",
                            "IndikatorGruppeID": -1,
                            "IndikatorFundKategorier": [
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 1,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "OK"
                                },
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 2,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Problem"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "IndikatorID": 1161,
                            "IndikatorNummer": 5,
                            "TrinNummer": 3,
                            "IndikatorTekst": "En gang årligt evaluerer ledelsen, hvorvidt der er sammenhæng mellem virksomhedsgrundlaget, apotekets praksis og de fastsatte kvalitetsmål, herunder personalets oplevelse af sammenhængen.",
                            "IndikatorGruppeID": -1,
                            "IndikatorFundKategorier": [
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 1,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "OK"
                                },
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 2,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Problem"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "IndikatorID": 1162,
                            "IndikatorNummer": 6,
                            "TrinNummer": 4,
                            "IndikatorTekst": "På baggrund af resultatet af kvalitetsovervågningen iværksætter ledelsen konkrete tiltag til eventuelle kvalitetsforbedringer og følger op på, om tiltagene har den ønskede effekt, jf. standard 1.2.1 Kvalitetsstyring.",
                            "IndikatorGruppeID": -1,
                            "IndikatorFundKategorier": [
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 1,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "OK"
                                },
                                {
                                    "FundKategoriID": 2,
                                    "FundKategoriTekst": "Problem"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "IKAS_reference": [
                        {
                            "referencenummer": 1,
                            "referencetekst": "Lov om apoteksvirksomhed. LBK nr. 855 af 04/08/2008"
                        },
                        {
                            "referencenummer": 2,
                            "referencetekst": "Strategi for apotekerne i Danmark – Medicin og sundhed med omtanke"
                        }
                    ],
                    "IKAS_faq": []
                },
```

```js
(function() {

  var stdCtrl = function($scope, $http) {

    var onSucces = function(response) {
      $scope.data = response.data.Standarder;
    };

    var onError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = reason;
    };

    $http.post("http://testwebserver:65/Standard/Apotek").then(onSucces, onError);
    $scope.data = " .... ";
    $scope.repoSortOrder = "-SektorID";
    $scope.SektorID = "";
    $scope.Kategori = "";
    $scope.Tema = "";
    $scope.Titel = "";
    $scope.Formaal = "";
    
    $scope.onSelectStandard = function(input) {
      return (angular.isDefined(input) && input !== '');
    };

    $scope.renderPage = function(value) {
      $scope.IKAS_standard = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.Standarder.IKAS_standard[value], function(IKAS_standard, index) {
        console.log(IKAS_standard);
        angular.forEach(IKAS_standard, function(IKAS_standarder) {
          $scope.IKAS_standard.push(IKAS_standarder);
        });
      });
    };

  };

  var app = angular.module("stdViewer", []);
  app.controller("stdCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", stdCtrl]);

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="stdViewer" ng-controller="stdCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="Standarder in data track by $index">
    <div ng-show="{{Standarder.SektorNavn != SektorNavn}}">
      <li ng-init="$parent.SektorID = Standarder.SektorID"></li>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="{{Standarder.SektorID == SektorID}}">
      <div ng-show="{{IKAS_standard.Kategori == Kategori}}"></div>
      <div ng-show="{{IKAS_standard.Titel != Titel}}">
        
        <div>
          <select ng-model="SelectedStandardId">
            <option ng-repeat="IKAS_standard in Standarder.IKAS_standard" value="{{IKAS_standard.StandardID}}">{{IKAS_standard.Kode}} {{IKAS_standard.Titel}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <br>
          <hr>
        </div>

        <div ng-model="SelectedStandardId" ng-show="onSelectStandard(SelectedStandardId)">
          <div ng-repeat="indikator in Standarder.IKAS_standard.IKASindikator | filter:StandardID= + SelectedStandardId">
            <ul>
              <li>Kode: {{std.IndikatorID}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @Simon Muhl Would it be possible to paste the Json of the response data or create one for testing.

Comment: hi . I need to display all the indikators under the list from the standard i choose from the list. ( standard = "1.1.1 'Some text'"

Comment: My proxy block "http://testwebserver:65/Standard/Apotek" request, could you paste json response here ?

Comment: I have pasted one a the top - sorry for bad layout. It contains 1 Standard with 6 indikatores

Answer (score 0):

Add filter to a first ng-repeat. Then repeat over filtered IKAS_standard collection:

Try this:

```
<div ng-model="SelectedStandardId">
  <div ng-repeat="IKAS_standard in Standarder.IKAS_standard | matchId:SelectedStandardId">
    <div ng-repeat="indikator in IKAS_standard.IKAS_indikator">
      <ul>
         <li>Kode: {{indikator.IndikatorID}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Full source

```js
var app = angular.module("stdViewer", []);

app.controller("stdCtrl", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
      "SektorID": 2,
      "IKAS_standard": [{
        "StandardID": 170,
        "Kode": "1.1.1",
        "IKAS_indikator": [{
          "IndikatorID": 1157
        }, {
          "IndikatorID": 1158
        }, {
          "IndikatorID": 1159
        }]
      }, {
        "StandardID": 200,
        "Kode": "1.1.2",
        "IKAS_indikator": [{
          "IndikatorID": 2001
        }, {
          "IndikatorID": 2002
        }, {
          "IndikatorID": 2003
        }]
      }]
    }];
  }
]);

app.filter('matchId', function() {
  return function(items, standardID) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if (item.StandardID == standardID) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="stdViewer" ng-controller="stdCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="Standarder in data track by $index">
    
    <div>
      <select ng-model="SelectedStandardId">
        <option ng-repeat="IKAS_standard in Standarder.IKAS_standard" value="{{IKAS_standard.StandardID}}">{{IKAS_standard.Kode}} {{IKAS_standard.Titel}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div ng-model="SelectedStandardId">
      <div ng-repeat="IKAS_standard in Standarder.IKAS_standard | matchId:SelectedStandardId">
        <div ng-repeat="indikator in IKAS_standard.IKAS_indikator">
          <ul>
            <li>Kode: {{indikator.IndikatorID}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not working.  It need to loop over the IKAS_indikator array for a IKAS_Standard where the "kode:" is the one i choose from the list. Hop U understand the problem because it is a bit hard to explain

Comment: i cant get the List to show data any more with the new ng-options

Comment: I think, i got it: http://plnkr.co/edit/1xTUG9xxjGTdfHnRjiDS?p=info  If it is what you need, i will update the answer